# What ball-joint cup piece or configuration of pieces is shown in this render?

Tags: part-identification, ldd

What is the name of this particular ball-cup, or piece combination that forms the thigh component circled below?

I have been unable to identify the gray cup piece when comparing it to other parts in the LEGO Digital Designer. I have ruled out this as a third party part, as the original MOC shown here was created in the LDD as well.

[image: Joint configuration]

Comment: The reason these parts were not showing up in LDD is because they are included in the LDD Extended theme. To activate, navigate to (View> New Themes > LDD Extended) in Lego Digital Designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top piece shown here is the [LEGO Ball Joint with Ball Socket (74261 / 98613)](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-ball-joint-with-ball-socket-74261-98613) connected to a [LEGO Brick 2 x 2 with Ball Socket and Axlehole (Wide Socket) (92013)](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-brick-2-x-2-with-ball-socket-and-axlehole-wide-socket-92013).

[image]

[image]